# Font Awesome :hover visibility attribute error

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying toggle between two font awesome icons on hover, but the visibility attribute does not seem to be updating. I initially set the fa-circle to invisible, but would like it to be visible on hover.  I would also like fa-circle-thin to be invisible on hover, as it is currently visible.  The angle-down icon seems to be updating color on hover, so I am confused as to why the other two icons would not update.

```css
a {
   color: #004E7b;
}

.fa-circle-thin:hover {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.fa-circle {
   visibility: hidden;
   color: #004e7b;
}

.fa-circle:hover {
   visibility: visible;
   color: #004e7b;
}

.fa-angle-down:hover {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-stack-2x"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pingo_/sw6w3vLg/

Please see if you can help.

Thanks !

EDIT:

Fiddle with solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/pingo_/u3vkbg8v/

Comment: Also tried this and had no luck:                                                                      `.fa-circle-thin:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fa-circle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fa-circle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #004e7b;
}`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. I think I see what you're trying to achieve. So if someone hovers on the fa-angle-down icon, it will change to another icon, correct?

Comment: @LansanaCamara wanted the fa-circle-thin to toggle to fa-circle on hover.  Was able to get the color change on fa-angle down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `.fa-stack:hover > .fa-circle` instead of `.fa-circle:hover`.

```css
@import 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
a {
  color: #004E7b;
}
.fa-circle {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #004e7b;
}
.fa-stack:hover > .fa-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #004e7b;
}
.fa-angle-down:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-stack-2x"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: @pingo Yes, you need 15 reputation points in order to [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). But you can [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want.